# Using c++ Lambda Expression

Tags: c++, list, c++11, lambda

I don't really understand Lambda expressions very well.
I created a list that takes in a struct "brute";

```
typedef struct brute{
int entry;
string secWord;
string secHex;
}decrypt;

typedef list<brute*>Unsolved;
```

I then try to use the for_each to iterate through the list.

```
char combo[] = {'a','a','b','c');
std::for_each(unsolved.begin(), unsolved.end(),[&combo](int i )
{

});
```

[&combo} is what I'm trying to capture. 
I have 3 questions: is "int i" the iterator for the list? How  do i access a member that is inside my unsolved list? Lastly do i need to define that my return value should be a char[]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) will expect a unary predicate that takes `brute*` or `brute*&`, something of the form

```
T foo(brute*);
```

would do. It ignores the return value. So your `for_each` call using a lambda could have this form:

```
std::array<char, 4> combo{'a','a','b','c'};
std::for_each(unsolved.begin(), unsolved.end(),[&combo](brute*& b) { .... } );
```

where I have used an `std::array` because it has simpler copy/assignment semantics than a plain array.

So, to answer the questions,

> is "int i" the iterator for the list?

No

> How do i access a member that is inside my unsolved list?

As shown in the example

> Lastly do i need to define that my return value should be a char[]?

The return value gets ignored. If you need it then you need another algorithm.